# Does it matter if I omit the 'val' keyword when adding a parameter/property to an enum class, doesn't seem to make any difference to the enum entries

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, class, enums, properties

When creating an enum class I am unsure what the difference is between adding adding val to a parameter and not. When providing arguments for said parameter for each enum entry there seems to be no difference. Hopefully someone can explain.

**This is without 'val'**

[image: image_1]

**This is with 'val**

[image: image_2]

Thanks.

I have tried looking everywhere, the only difference it seems is that one is a parameter and one is a property but i dont really understand the difference. I am still fairly new to kotlin/android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't add `val` you can't access it later, it won't be a property of the class, it would be just an argument that you have passed to the constructor and it would be pointless in an enum

```
enum class ScreenSize(width: Int, height: Int) { // not declared as val
    Big(1000, 1600),
    Medium(700, 1000),
    Small(500, 700)
}

fun drawScreen(screenSize: ScreenSize) {
    //Compile error
    drawRect(
        width = screenSize.width,
        height = screenSize.height,
    )
}

fun drawRect(width: Int, height: Int) {
    .....
}
```

Comment: Ah ok yeh that makes sense, thanks so much for clearing that up.

Comment: you're welcome, if the answer makes sense to you, marking it as accepted answer would be appreciated